# gunzip -tv reports 'extra field of 6 bytes ignored'

Tags: unix, gzip

I am checking some compressed gz files that a program downloads, and when running:

```
gunzip -v -t file.gz
```

I get the following message, thousands of times:

```
gzip: ./file.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to its sources: http://www.gzip.org/#sources, gzip just skips EXTRA_FIELD section from the archive header. gzip itself does not fill the section, so it should be another archiver to fill this section (for example, it may mark that archive was created by the program this way). Another probability is that archive file is just broken, of course.

You can modify the sources to see, what exactly are the bytes skipped. Just add output inside this condition:

```
if ((flags & EXTRA_FIELD) != 0) {
```

in gzip.c.

Comment: `gunzip -v -t` gives a final `OK` for the file, so it looks like the file is correct, but that the EXTRA_FIELD flag in the header is skipped. Makes sense.